# "catching is not a function" exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception

I'm having an issue on JBoss (6.4.14 GA) running jQuery 3.1.1 (or 3.2.1).  As soon as a page loads and the documet.ready function executes I get the following error:

> jquery.js:formatted:8142 Uncaught TypeError: aj.then(...).catching is not a function
>           at bw.fn.init.bw.fn.ready (jquery.js:formatted:8142)
>           at srs.js:1

The jQuery code throwing this error is:

```
var readyList = jQuery.Deferred();

jQuery.fn.ready = function( fn ) {

    readyList
        .then( fn )

        // Wrap jQuery.readyException in a function so that the lookup
        // happens at the time of error handling instead of callback
        // registration.
        .catching( function( error ) {
            jQuery.readyException( error );
        } );

    return this;
};
```

I do not get this error when running my application on Tomcat 7.

I've been researching this error for several days and have been unable to find any references to this specific error (catching is not a function), so looking for some help in determining the cause of this error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the 'bw' object?  And did you mean catch? http://api.jquery.com/deferred.catch/

Comment: What is `catching()`? It's not a standard jQuery method, so unless you've added it - that's your issue.

Comment: [This](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.catch/)?

Comment: You probably need to catch the catching error ... ;)

Comment: Updated original question with raw jQuery source code causing the exception instead of compressed/compiled version.

Comment: If I look at the source code of jQuery at https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js the said line is: `.catch( function( error ) {`. Do you load jQuery from a CDN, or do you host it on your own server?

Comment: We do not use CDN because we have to make our version of jQuery Fortify compliant and there are several Fortify issues with jQuery "out of the box".  Unknown to me, we had made modifications that caused the error in question. I have restored our code via the link from Teemu and my issue now is that the yuicompressor-maven-plugin fails in the maven build:  jquery-3.1.1.js [3873:9]: missing name after . operator
[ERROR] ...jquery-3.1.1.js:line 3873:column 9:missing name after . operator

Comment: .....continuation of previous post....line 3873 is 

.catch( function( error ) { 

in the jQuery.fn.ready function definition.

Answer (score 0):

`catching` **is not** a method of jquery's deferred, you are maybe looking for [`catch`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.catch/).

For debugging purpose, you can list properties of an object using [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](//mdn.io/Object.getOwnPropertyNames) and see which one they have. In your case, executing the code below would have helped you find the error:

```
var debugValue = aj.then(bS)
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(debugValue))
```

Comment: So why is jQuery code referencing a Deferred function that they don't provide with Deferred?

Comment: They do provide a function, it is just not called `catching` but `catch`